How to fix values of LANGEVIN_GAMMA in VASP?
While running MD simulation in NpT ensemble in VASP, when using a Langevin thermostat (MDALGO=3), it is prescribed to set the LANGEVIN_GAMMA tag. However, I need help determining my system's appropriate values for different atomic species.
My system's POSCAR looks like following
C  Cl  F  H  Li  N  O  P  S 
 30  36  2  75  217  1  24  41  182 

My questions are:-

What are the typical values for LANGEVIN_GAMMA for common elements
like C, H, and O?
How can I determine these values if they are not readily available in the literature?
Are there general guidelines or empirical methods to estimate these coefficients for
different types of atoms?


The Langevin thermostat works by adding a random force to the atoms, and then damps out the motions to reach thermodynamic consistencyt. The strengths of the force and damping, and the correlation time of the force are inversely proportional to each other. The LANGEVIN_GAMMA is that time constant, and VASP does them per-element. There are a few consequences of this mechanism for molecular dynamics:

The thermostat is effective when the adding (force) and removal (damping) of kinetic energy match some physical process that moves kinetic energy in the material or molecule. In practice, this timescale is the period of a phonon or a vibration that has reasonable contributions from the motion of the relevant atoms.
The dynamics on timescales faster than the time constant of the thermostat are suspect and should not be trusted.
There is no "typical value" for an element since the relevant timescales will change by material. Optimal damping for C in diamond or in a MXene will be completely different from that in a molecule such as CH4.

So what should one do?

Set the thermostat constant (LANGEVIN_GAMMA) to the frequency in THz or ps^-1 of a vibration that has a strong contribution from that element. For example, if the Cl has a strong vibration at 15 THz (I'm making up an arbitrary number), then it makes sense to set its LANGEVIN_GAMMA to 15.
You do not need to thermostat every species. VASP tells you how you can exclude some of the species from Langevin thermostatting. This is relevant if you want to analyse, e.g., something about the fast dynamics of some bond and need to not perturb it with thermostatting. For example, if you care about Li motion (again, arbitrary species), then you can thermostat a few other species and leave the Li as Newtonian.
Consider other thermostats if relevant and available, and if representing fast dynamics is of interest. Nosé and CSVR (in LAMMPS) are perfectly fine, but VASP only has Langevin and Nosé to my knowledge.

Related questions (and their answers!):

Langevin vs Nosé–Hoover thermostat
Selection of appropriate Langevin damping parameter for MD of solid metal
Empirically determining thermostat damping factor

